# R - 'raster' package - RasterLayer ("raster") does not extract to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame ("sp"); Simply returns NULL object

Tags: r, shapefile, coordinate-systems, r-raster, r-sp

Using the `raster` package, I have read-in two datasets, one ASCII raster and one ESRI shapefile. I want to extract the raster's (water temperature) data to the full extent of the shapefile, which is a lake shoreline.

The ESRI shapefile gets treated as a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` when read-in using the `shapefile()` function.

`shapefile <- shapefile("shore.shp",verbose=TRUE)`

I used the `raster()` function to read-in the ASCII raster.

`raster <- raster("1995_001.asc",native=TRUE,crs="+proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m")`

The coordinate reference information for the shapefile is:

`+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0`

That of the raster (i.e. coerced to the following using the `crs` argument in the `raster()` function):

`+proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +towgs84=0,0,0`

I then used the `spTransform()` function in the `rgdal` package to coerce the spatial reference of the shapefile to that of the raster.

`spTransform(shapefile, CRS(projection(raster)))`

Finally, I submitted the following:

`extract(raster,shapefile,method="simple",fun=mean,small=TRUE,na.rm=TRUE,df=FALSE)`

However, `extract()` simply returns `NULL` object of `list` type. I assume that this issue is borne out of the explicit coercion of the coordinate references.

In addition, here are the results of using the `show()` function on each dataset:

`> show(raster)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1024, 1024, 1048576  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1800, 1800  (x, y)
extent      : -10288022, -8444822, 4675974, 6519174  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : -9999, 8.97  (min, max)`

`> show(shapefile)
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 597568.5, 998261.6, 278635.3, 668182.2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3
names       :            AREA,   PERIMETER,    HECTARES 
min values  : 59682523455.695, 5543510.075, 5968252.346 
max values  : 59682523455.695, 5543510.075, 5968252.346`

I have searched a plethora of similar questions on these forums with no resolution. Could someone lend me a (virtual) hand?

Thank you very much, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This (data that does not appear to spatially overlap) is a common problem stemming from confusion about coordinate reference systems. This can happen for a few possible reasons.

1) the regions actually do not overlap

2) Perhaps your assignment of the crs to the RasterLayer is wrong (or that of the polygons). Please show the object (`show(raster)`); that is almost always helpful when asking a question about the `raster` package.

3) You do not assign the result of spTransform. Remember that *R* generally does not do 'in-place' modifications. Make sure to do `shapefile <- spTransform(shapefile, crs(raster))`

Always do a sanity test, and work your way back until things work. The place to start here would be to do

```
plot(raster)
plot(shapefile, add=TRUE)
```

To see if any of the polygons plot on top of the raster data.

If that does not work, look at the extents. For example like this (by the way, this also shows how you can create a self-contained reproducible example/question, that others can actually answer):

```
library(raster)
# the spatial parameters of your raster
r <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100, xmn=-10288022, xmx=-8444822, ymn=4675974, ymx=6519174, crs="+proj=merc +datum=WGS84")
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

# the extent of your SpatialPolygons
ep <- extent(597568.5, 998261.6, 278635.3, 668182.2)
p <- as(ep, 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(p) <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83"

# tranform both data set to longlat
rgeo <- projectRaster(r, crs='+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
pgeo <- spTransform(p, CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'))

# plot on top of Google map
library(dismo)
e <- union(extent(rgeo), extent(pgeo))
g <- gmap(e,lonlat=TRUE)
plot(g, inter=TRUE)
plot(extent(rgeo), add=TRUE, col='red', lwd=2)
plot(pgeo, add=TRUE, col='blue', lwd=2)
```

[image]

Clearly the two data sources do not overlap. Only you know which of the two may be correct, and you can now start to look into why the other one is in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You're correct in that the two datasets do not overlap spatially. I have applied each of your suggestions, but with the same result as before.

It turns out that the ASCII raster does not have a coordinate system defined upon read-in and examination of 'show(raster)'.

How might I go about defining the coordinate system and projection for both the 'raster' and 'shapefile' in R, so that they overlap spatially?

Comment: I know that the ASCII file does not store any CRS infromation (it is a really bad file format in many ways). If you can show us `show(raster)` then we can at least assess whether `crs="+proj=merc +datum=WGS84` is plausible (unless you know this for *sure*). I would suggest that you edit your question, and also include `show(shapefile)`